# Android list - edittext in header of list

Tags: android, focus, xamarin.android, android-edittext, listactivity

I have a List in Monodroid which has a header with an EditText. The problem is that EditText not getting focus properly. Here is how it works:

1. If you touch the EditText, the keyboard comes up correctly, but if you press any key, nothing happens.
2. Hide the keyboard with the back button
3. If you touch the EditText again it works correctly

I tried to debug it and first time `FocusChange` event fires twice, first with the `HasFocus = true`, and second time with `HasFocus = false`.

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here is what solved my problem:

I set this to my ListView in XML:

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

And to my ListView in code:

```
ListView.ItemsCanFocus = true;
```

And this to my EditText:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

And Voilá it works like a charm. Thank you Bradley!

Comment: using code it works as expected, EditText v = new EditText(this); v.setText("kb");mycontactlistview.addHeaderView(v);

Comment: Yes, if i set any text to the EditText it works correctly, but i want to set a placeholder text and let the user to enter any text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting the EditText above your ListView in the layout xml instead of adding it to the header.

I have ran into this situation before and could never get 100% reliability out of a single solution. If a brute force approach is the only solution, try different combinations of the following properties on the ListView object: DescendantFocusability, ItemsCanFocus, Focusable.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i managed to solve it. I updated my question according to your suggestions.